# Python: Data Getting

Tags: python, input, data-collection

Im trying to find out how to get certain data from a file in the easiest way possible. I have searched all over the internet but can't find anything. I want to be able to do this:

File.txt:

```
data1 = 1
data2 = 2
```

but i want to get only data1 like so,

```
p = open('file.txt')
f = p.get(data1)
print(f)
```

Any Ideas, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
        key, val = f.readline().split('=')
        if key.strip() == 'data1':  # if data1 is not the first line
            # do something with value and data
```

Comment: think that strip not removes the inner blank spaces so key == 'data1' fails cause it test key == 'data1 '

Comment: readline() just reads one line so if data1 is not in the first line you can retrieve it cause are not any iteration

Comment: yes,you are right,but in the file maybe the user just want to the first line.

Comment: the questions says that he wants to read data1 so to ensure that you can iterate over the lines of the file and check for the key

Comment: in fact I think the data user want to read is a config file,so your map solution is better.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        key, val = line.split('=')
        key = key.strip()
        val = val.strip() 
        if key == 'data1':  # if data1 is not the first line
            # do something with value and data
```

using map:

```
from operator import methodcaller
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        key, val = map(methodcaller("strip", " "), line.split('='))
        if key == "data1":
             # do something with value and data
```

Comment: you just want to take data1 string? or the value of data1 or both?

Comment: You might even just use `str.strip` rather than `methodcaller('strip')` if you can guarantee that `line.split` will return a list of `str` instances.

Answer (score 0):

If you know you only want `data1` which is on the first line, you can do

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    key, val = tuple(x.strip() for x in f.readline().split('='))
```

The list comprehension is used to remove the whitespace from each string.

Comment: you can't call strip on a list object, think it causes and error.

Comment: Yup, it does.  I fixed that. Thanks